# Adding header and footer to layout

Tags: html, css

I have problem, I editing some layout and I have problem. Here's that  [layout](http://djmajkel.pl/dd/index.php) . When we click on some side we have a header and footer, but I would like to add this footer and header on the other way, like on this  [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXlQm.png), could you help me?

Comment: It would help a lot if you added the current HTML & CSS

Comment: I'm afraid that I cannot open your layout link, please replace it. And can you post some of your code that you have done

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use css to edit the height of the `side` class.

```
.side {
position: fixed;
top: 66px;
height: calc(100% - 132px);
```

The calc value in css is fairly well supported from internet explorer 9 upwards
http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: you could also use bottom 66px (if the footer is 66px height)

Comment: @pete That's actually a much simpler and more compatible way.

Comment: @PhilipAbbott It's much better, but if you lookup update site here's [link] http://djmajkel.pl/dd/upd/index.php [link] you can see lines on layout, and if you change a size of browser's window it doesn't look good.

Comment: Add to the .side-right and .side-left classes z-index: 1;

Comment: @PhilipAbbott Now its fantastic, last question, is there possibility to make that footer will be always out  the forground, but on bottom still visible,  if we have site and I will add some text to footer and header they  will  occupy most of site. If I remove fixed position from footer it desapeard.

Comment: OK last one. Move the footer div inside the content div and change the positioning on the footer div to position: relative. You'll have to sort it out yourself from here though.